# SQL Server 2012 First_Value Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck in a case since 2 days and I need your assistance please.
the table as below :

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K82WP.jpg)

SR  UID  Flag   Fees
1   AAA  1     100.00
2   AAA  0     0.00
3   AAA  0     0.00
4   AAA  1     120.00
5   AAA  0     0.00
6   AAA  0     0.00
7   AAA  1     140.00
1   BBB  1     200.00
2   BBB  0     0.00
3   BBB  0     0.00
4   BBB  0     0.00
5   BBB  0     0.00
6   BBB  0     0.00
7   BBB  1     400.00

how  I can use First_value function to replace the 0.00 values in fees column with the first value where Flag =1 partition by UID

the result should be as the following 
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGM50.jpg)

SR  UID Flag   Fees   First_Value
1   AAA  1    100.00   100.00
2   AAA  0    0.00     100.00
3   AAA  0    0.00     100.00
4   AAA  1    120.00   120.00
5   AAA  0    0.00     120.00
6   AAA  0    0.00     120.00
7   AAA  1    140.00   140.00
1   BBB  1    200.00   200.00
2   BBB  0    0.00     200.00
3   BBB  0    0.00     200.00
4   BBB  0    0.00     200.00
5   BBB  0    0.00     200.00
6   BBB  0    0.00     200.00
7   BBB  1    400.00   400.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea, using `FIRST_VALUE` like the Op was trying to:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (SR int, UID char(3), Flag bit, Fees decimal(5,2));
INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES
    (1,'AAA',1,100.00),
    (2,'AAA',0,0.00  ),
    (3,'AAA',0,0.00  ),
    (4,'AAA',1,120.00),
    (5,'AAA',0,0.00  ),
    (6,'AAA',0,0.00  ),
    (7,'AAA',1,140.00),
    (1,'BBB',1,200.00),
    (2,'BBB',0,0.00  ),
    (3,'BBB',0,0.00  ),
    (4,'BBB',0,0.00  ),
    (5,'BBB',0,0.00  ),
    (6,'BBB',0,0.00  ),
    (7,'BBB',1,400.00);

WITH Groups AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UID ORDER BY SR) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UID, Flag ORDER BY SR) AS Grp
    FROM #Sample)
SELECT SR, UID, Flag, Fees,
       FIRST_VALUE(Fees) OVER (PARTITION BY UID, CASE Grp WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE Grp END ORDER BY SR)
FROM Groups
ORDER BY UID, SR;

DROP TABLE #Sample
```